# System.ArguementException while calling RenderAsync() in windows phone RT app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

```
Grid TestGrid = new Grid();
TestGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);
TestGrid.Height = 500;
TestGrid.Width = 500;
await bitmapRender.RenderAsync(TestGrid, 500, 500);
```

This code in its last statement gives me the following error:

*System.ArgumentException*

*Value does not fall within the expected range.*

What's wrong in this apparently simple code?

**Edit:** Futher details on the bug:

{System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Picture_Slide.MainPage.d__0.MoveNext()}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps it's the same as in WINRT, it can't render something which is not in the visual tree, or in popup, etc... Look here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx
From 'XAML visuals and RenderTargetBitmap capture capabilities' title

Comment: In which case how do I achieve what WritableBitmap can in a Silverlight app? I need to generate it from code without having it in the visual tree.

Comment: @Aditya On WinRT you can render only those elements that are in VisualTree - [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22896979/2681948).

Comment: you should add it to the visual tree and hide somehow if you don't need it on the screen. Maybe place under some border

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use `RenderAsync` in a `backgroundAgent` use `XamlRenderingBackgroundTask`

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43295c90-43e8-4b08-8a25-958a1c3d0a0b/explanation-on-windowsuixamlmediaxamlrenderingbackgroundtask?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK