# Save Photo in media library windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm getting photo path from a list view and showing image in detail screen.
Detail page Code is here.

```
 //Imaged  is my image control in Xaml.

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var imagePath = e.Parameter as string;
        imaged.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


        var imgsource = imaged.Source;
    }
```

I want to save this picture in media Library, by clicking save button event.

Here is my Save button event code.

```
    private async void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_SaveToPictures(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();

           // picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG File", new List<string>() { ".png" });
            picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG image", new string[] { ".jpg" });
            picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG image", new string[] { ".png" });
            picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("BMP image", new string[] { ".bmp" });
            picker.DefaultFileExtension = ".png";



            picker.SuggestedFileName = "bomdiaimg";
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

            StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
           // StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAndContinue();
            if (file != null) 
            { 
               RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitMap = new RenderTargetBitmap();  



            await  renderTargetBitMap.RenderAsync(imaged, (int)imaged.Width, (int)imaged.Height); 

            var pixels = await renderTargetBitMap.GetPixelsAsync();



            using (IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))  
             { 
                  var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, randomAccessStream);  
                  byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();  
                  encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)renderTargetBitMap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitMap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, bytes); await encoder.FlushAsync();  
             }
            }

    }
```

I'm not able to save picture the error is that

Here the error is an exception.

```
      StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

SOme times green line under this method "which shows that use picksavefile and continue"  But when I use this method then error display. not able to understand this issue. how can I save my picture in media library

Comment: If you are looking for a method to save *Image* to file, then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22896979/2681948) can help you.

Comment: Not helpful.. would you please send me exact answer by my code?

Answer (score 0):

The `SaveJpeg` method is an extension method from the namespace `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions`. Add a using at the top of the source file:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions;
```

And, possibly you meant to use `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap` instead of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`?

Comment: No, not getting able to resolve this. the main theme is to save picture by using SaveJpeg.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to help you resolve... Can you use System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap instead of Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap? I am guessing you have taken some sample code from somewhere and you can't find the SaveJpeg method. That method applies to System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap.

Comment: I'm not able to get this reference . not getting this by add reference

Comment: Yup.. I got this sample code and want to implement same thing in my test app

Comment: Extensions.SaveJpeg is within the library Microsoft.Phone. System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap is in the assembly System.Windows. Do you have those references in your project? What exactly is the project type? (windows phone 8.1, universal app, portable class library)

Comment: @Arsal Maybe providing a link to the sample code will be useful

Comment: I don't have these references in my project. My project type is windows phone 8.1.  More is not not able to add these references in my project. I searched in Nugut package ,,or tried to add these references . please help me to resolve this also

Comment: I'm trying to do this with this link. https://dzone.com/articles/how-create-folder-windows

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want use RenderTargetBitMap for save control image. Please check this example code.

```
FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker(); 
picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPG File", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });  
 StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync(); if (file != null) 
{ 
   RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitMap = new RenderTargetBitmap();  
//With this method we can make our XAML elements in an image. await       


renderTargetBitMap.RenderAsync(grdRender, (int)grdRender.Width, (int)grdRender.Height); 

var pixels = await renderTargetBitMap.GetPixelsAsync();



using (IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))  
 { 
      var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, randomAccessStream);  
      byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();  
      encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)renderTargetBitMap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitMap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, bytes); await encoder.FlushAsync();  
 }
}
```

Comment: The above code is not working, Where I have to give my own picture from list view.?  Exception comes for this code

Comment: Replace "grdRender" for "imaged" that is the control. Here you can see a example code https://github.com/Satur01/Demo01RenderTargetBitMap

Comment: StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();   This line create exception,,I couldn't get the solution. The above sample in comment is for windows